# Short exact sequence terminating at $\mathbb{Z}/2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

Suppose we have the following short exact sequence of abelian groups:
$$
0 \rightarrow A \xrightarrow{a} B \xrightarrow{b} \mathbb{Z}/2 \rightarrow 0.
$$

Under which conditions do we have that $b^{-1}(1)$ is isomorphic, as a set, to $A$?

I suspect this happens when the sequence splits (so then we have $B \cong A \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2$, and the preimage of $1$ under $b$ is just a copy of $A$), but I am having some trouble showing this rigorously. Also, is it true that this sequence always splits?

Comment: I suppose by isomorphism  $b^{-1}(1)\cong A$ you mean that of abelian groups. But why should the coset $b^{-1}(1)$ be a group?

Comment: @Phil.Z actually no, it's sufficient for me to show they are isomorphic as sets, I'll add this clarification

Comment: Well, then the answer is always, since $b^{-1}(1)$ is a coset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is a bijection between $b^{-1}(1)$ and $A$, then you always have one, as $b^{-1}(1)$ is the coset of $\ker(b)$ not containing zero, and $\ker(b)$ is isomorphic to $A$ by exactness.

Comment: I see, I was overlooking the fact we should view $b^{-1}$ as a coset, so it has the same cardinality as $\ker(b) \cong A$. Thanks!